# Historical Table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have two tables; the first named `PAYMENT` and the second is a historical table named `RecordPay`.

I have two triggers, the first one is for insert in order to insert into the historical tables records from `Payment` table.

Here is the code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[INSERT_HIST]
ON  [dbo].[PAYMENT]
FOR  INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
     DECLARE @User_op varchar(50) 
     DECLARE @RGNO varchar(50)

     DECLARE @PAYEUR varchar(50)
     DECLARE @DATESYS SMALLDATETIME 
     DECLARE @RG_DATE SMALLDATETIME 
     DECLARE @RG_Montant varchar(50)

     SELECT @User_op = cbUserName 
     FROM cbUserSession 
     WHERE cbSession = @@SPID

     SELECT @PAYEUR = CT_NumPayeur FROM INSERTED

     SELECT @DATESYS = GETDATE()
     SELECT @RG_Montant = RG_Montant FROM INSERTED
     SELECT @RG_DATE = RG_DATE FROM INSERTED
     SELECT @RGNO = RG_No FROM INSERTED

     INSERT INTO RecordPay (RG_NO, PAYEUR, CAISSIER, Montant, DATESYS,   DATECAI)
     VALUES (@RGNO, @PAYEUR, @user_op, @RG_Montant, @DATESYS, @RG_DATE)
```

This works well, my problem when I delete a row from `PAYMENT`, in `RecordPay` the record exists, and then when I insert another row in `PAYMENT` I had two `RG_NO` whith the same number.

For example I insert a row in `PAYMENT` with RG_NO=1 then I deleted, and I create another row with RG_NO=2, in the recordPay (historical table) i get two lines with RG_NO=1.

Here is the trigger for delete but it does not work

```
 ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DEL_HIST]
 ON  [dbo].[PAYMENT]
 AFTER  DELETE
 AS 
 BEGIN


 DECLARE @User_op varchar(50) 
 DECLARE @RGNO varchar(50)

 DECLARE @PAYEUR varchar(50)
 DECLARE @DATESYS SMALLDATETIME 
 DECLARE @RG_DATE SMALLDATETIME 
 DECLARE @RG_Montant varchar(50)


 SELECT @PAYEUR = CT_NumPayeur FROM DELETED

 SELECT @RG_Montant = RG_Montant FROM DELETED
 SELECT @RG_DATE = RG_DATE FROM DELETED
SELECT @RGNO = RG_No FROM DELETED

DELETE FROM RECORDPAY  WHERE  
RG_NO=@RGNO and PAYEUR= @PAYEUR  and CAISSIER=@user_op and Montant=@RG_Montant 
END
```

Comment: Youve made the classical error of triggers; assuming there is only 1 row in `INSERTED`. Another point - in payment processing rows are *never* deleted, a payment reversal is typically done by putting through another payment to negate the first.

Comment: thank you for your response, but can you give an example . I don't get it very well

Comment: If you wanted to delete a payment of `5`, you wouldnt delete that row out of payments, you would enter a new payment of `-5` to balance it out

Comment: Why are you SHOUTING AT US? Typing your title all in CAPS will not get you answers any more quickly, it's irritating, and it's extremely rude. We're all capable of reading quite well here, and you don't have to SHOUT to get attention. You also don't have to BEG FOR HELP IN ALL CAPS. Someone will help if they can without your begging for it. Please be polite and STOP YELLING.

Comment: what are you saying Ken!!!!!!  I am not rude, I didn't make attention when I wrote the title. PS  I am here to learn. If you can help thank you're welcom else I don't ant to discuss any thing out of topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger will **BREAK** as soon as an `INSERT` statement inserts more than 1 row at a time - because in that case, your trigger gets called **once** for the `INSERT` statement, and `Inserted` will contain multiple rows.

Which one of those 10 rows are you selecting from here??

```
 SELECT @PAYEUR = CT_NumPayeur FROM INSERTED
 SELECT @RG_Montant = RG_Montant FROM INSERTED
 SELECT @RG_DATE = RG_DATE FROM INSERTED
 SELECT @RGNO = RG_No FROM INSERTED
```

It's arbitrary and non-deterministic - and you will simply **ignore** all other rows in `Inserted`.

You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[INSERT_HIST]
ON  [dbo].[PAYMENT]
FOR  INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
     DECLARE @User_op varchar(50) 

     SELECT @User_op = cbUserName 
     FROM cbUserSession 
     WHERE cbSession = @@SPID

     -- insert a record for ALL the rows that were inserted into 
     -- your history table in a single, elegant, set-based statement
     INSERT INTO RecordPay (RG_NO, PAYEUR, CAISSIER, Montant, DATESYS,   DATECAI)
         SELECT
             RG_No, CT_NumPayeur, @User_op, RG_Montant, SYSDATETIME(), RG_Date
         FROM
             Inserted
```